# Perturbation of relativistic hydrogen

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, resource-recommendations, potential, hydrogen

Is there anyone that can provide a source for a relativistic hydrogen atom that is placed in a finite potential well? I am trying to find the new ground state energy for a relativistic electron that has the normal coulomb interaction inside a confinement radius $R$ and the coulomb interaction plus a scalar potential beyond the confinement radius.

Comment: There was a PhD dissertation at the University of Wisconsin, Madison by Tom Kirkman that discussed the hydrogen atom in extreme magnetic fields (e.g., near a pulsar) that would probably cover this topic.  However, I am not sure if there was ever an electronic copy of the dissertation made.

Comment: Are you looking for relativistic version of this: https://doi.org/10.1063/1.438077 ?

Comment: @A.V.S. Yes. I have not been able to find one at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Quite possibly this has not been done, yet.

Here is quite recent paper (December 2017):

> Rojas, R. A., N. Aquino, and A. Flores‐Riveros. *Fine structure in the hydrogen atom boxed in a spherical impenetrable cavity.* International Journal of Quantum Chemistry (2017). [DOI:10.1002/qua.25584](https://doi.org/10.1002/qua.25584).
>
> The spectrum of the hydrogen atom confined in a spherical impenetrable box of radius $R_c$ has been investigated by many authors up to date, but not at the level of relativistic corrections. It is well known that, as $R_c$ diminishes, all energy levels and the pressure increase very rapidly, whereas the polarizability goes to zero. In this report, we have computed the relativistic corrections that underlie the fine structure of the confined hydrogen atom, as a function of $R_c$. Such corrections correspond to relativistic kinetic energy, spin-orbit coupling and the Darwin term, which are calculated in the frame of time-independent perturbation theory, for which, use was made of the exact confined hydrogen atom wave functions. We show that for a confinement radius of 0.5 au the relativistic corrections increase up to three orders of magnitude with respect to those corresponding to the free atom. As $R_c$ decreases, the kinetic energy correction and the spin-orbit coupling for $j=1/2$ become negative whereas their absolute value and the Darwin term, which is positive, increase very rapidly.

Authors use already known exact nonrelativistic wavefunctions for infinite potential well written in terms of confluent hypergeometric function, with its parameters determined by numerical solution of boundary condition.  These wavefunctions are plugged into the first order perturbation theory to determine relativistic corrections.

And authors promise in conclusion:

> Analysis of the effects on the fine structure when the atom is placed inside **soft spherical walls** is in progress.

So, either you have to wait, or do it yourself. The problem does not seem to be too difficult. Wavefunctions for nonrelativistic confined hydrogen atom in a finite well are also known:

> Ley‐Koo, E., & Rubinstein, S. (1979). *The hydrogen atom within spherical boxes with penetrable walls*. The Journal of Chemical Physics, 71(1), 351-357. [DOI:10.1063/1.438077](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.438077).

As one can expect, they are written in terms of the same confluent hypergeometric functions both inside and outside the well and its parameters are determined by matching boundary condition at $R_c$. So, once you have the wavefunctions it would be straightforward to compute relativistic corrections in the first order perturbation expansion.

One thing to note: you might have to include Darwin term ($\sim \delta'(r-R_c)$) for the border of the well. It was not an issue for impenetrable wall but might be relevant for well of finite depth.

Comment: I am actually in the process of doing it myself. I’m having trouble with the boundary conditions and what to do with the potential term. I’m actually just using the Dirac radial equations.

Comment: @Noon36:  Well, at least you will be able to check your calculations against this paper. As, for the boundary conditions you could model potential well of finite depth as a spherical capacitor: two spheres carrying opposite charges with radii $R-\epsilon$ and $R+\epsilon$. That way you have to stitch together only solutions of one type.

Comment: My boundary conditions:
$V(r)=\frac{-Ze^2}{r}$ for r<R,
$V(r)=V_0$ (where $V_0$ is in terms of $m_0*c^2$) for r>R

Comment: Strictly speaking that is not boundary conditions, that is your potential. Boundary conditions should tell you how to glue together solutions $r<R$ and $r>R$

Comment: Sorry, that is what I meant. Would you recommend those potentials for this type of problem? Or should the potential term for r>R still contain the coulomb potential as well as the scalar potential? at $r=R$, I set the equations equal to each other. for r<R, we have the normal confluent hypergeometric functions and for r>R, we have an exponential decaying solution (which is what is required as r goes to infinity).

Comment: @Noon36: If you could solve the equations both with and without Coulomb potential in area $r>R$ then you would have a ready test on sensitivity of your result to the model of confining box for your hydrogen atom. So if some effect would be present in both cases, then one could hope it would remain  even in more realistic situations.

Comment: I will try both. I may update this post sometime this week when I have some results. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here this issue is discussed in detail. But the article is in Russian.
https://inis.iaea.org/search/search.aspx?orig_q=RN:47070864